# Why axes arrows are not present?

Tags: plotting, syntax, plot-themes

Consider some test data

```
function1[number_, g_, lmin_, lmax_, c\[Tau]_] = 
  number*g^2 (Exp[-lmin/(c\[Tau]*10)] - Exp[-lmax/(c\[Tau]*10)]);

f1 = RegionPlot[
   function1[10^13, 10^g, 10^-2, 0.5, 10^c\[Tau]] >= 3, {c\[Tau], 
    Log10[0.00001], Log10[5*10^9]}, {g, -15, -1}];
f11 = {10^#[[1]], 10^#[[2]]} & /@ 
   Partition[Flatten[Cases[Normal@f1, Line[x_] :> x, Infinity]], 2];
f2 = RegionPlot[
   function1[10^16, 10^g, 0.5, 10, 10^c\[Tau]] >= 3, {c\[Tau], 
    Log10[0.00001], Log10[5*10^9]}, {g, -15, -1}];
f21 = {10^#[[1]], 10^#[[2]]} & /@ 
   Partition[Flatten[Cases[Normal@f2, Line[x_] :> x, Infinity]], 2];
f3 = RegionPlot[
   function1[10^18, 10^g, 10, 100, 10^c\[Tau]] >= 3, {c\[Tau], 
    Log10[0.00001], Log10[5*10^9]}, {g, -15, -1}];
f31 = {10^#[[1]], 10^#[[2]]} & /@ 
   Partition[Flatten[Cases[Normal@f3, Line[x_] :> x, Infinity]], 2];
```

I would like to plot it with arrows in the following way:

```
ListLogLogPlot[{f11, f21, f31}, Joined -> {True, True}, 
 Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 25], 
 PlotRange -> {{0.00001, 5*10^9}, {10^-11, 10^-2}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.003], Blue}, {Thickness[0.003], 
    Darker@Red}, {Thickness[0.003], 
    Darker@Darker@Green}, {Thickness[0.003], Darker@Gray}}, 
 AspectRatio -> 0.66, ImageSize -> Large, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
 FrameTicks -> None, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[0.07], 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[Style[#, 24] & /@ {"1", "2", "3"}, {0.77, 0.2}]]
```

However, the arrows do not show up:

[image]

Could you please tell me how to fix this problem?

Comment: Where did you specify that arrows should be drawn?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork `AxesStyle` is so interpreted. John, The problem is that the origin is not visible.  Try adding `AxesOrigin -> {10^5, 10^-5}` and adjust the origin as desired.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the origin is not visible. Try adding `AxesOrigin -> {10^5, 10^-5}` and adjust the origin as desired.

```
ListLogLogPlot[{f11, f21, f31}, Joined -> {True, True}, Frame -> True,
  FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 25], 
 PlotRange -> {{0.00001, 5*10^9}, {10^-11, 10^-2}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.003], Blue}, {Thickness[0.003], 
    Darker@Red}, {Thickness[0.003], 
    Darker@Darker@Green}, {Thickness[0.003], Darker@Gray}}, 
 AspectRatio -> 0.66, ImageSize -> Large, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
 FrameTicks -> None, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[0.07],
 AxesOrigin -> {10^5, 10^-5},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[Style[#, 24] & /@ {"1", "2", "3"}, {0.77, 0.2}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But why it does not work if I choose `AxesOrigin` to coincide with the boundary of PlotRange (`AxesOrigin -> {0.00001, 10^-11.}`)? Generically, there is some minimal margin after which the arrows do not show up.

Comment: @JohnTaylor Yes, the `Frame` has precedence over `Axes`. I don't know what the margin is, but it's around here: `AxesOrigin -> {0.00001, 10^-11.}, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1]`. Or this: `PlotRangePadding -> {{Scaled[.101], 0}, {Scaled[.1], 0}}, PlotLegends -> 
 Placed[Style[#, 24] & /@ {"1", "2", "3"}, {0.77, 0.25}]`